# Emoji count and analysis using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, emoji, sentiment-analysis, emoticons

I am working on a sentiment analysis topic and there are a lot of comments with emojis.

I would like to know if my code is correct or is there a way to optimize it as well?

**Code to do smiley count**

```
import pandas as pd
import regex as re
import emoji

# Assuming your DataFrame is called 'df' and the column with comments is 'Document'
comments = df['Document']

# Initialize an empty dictionary to store smiley counts and types
smiley_data = {'Smiley': [], 'Count': [], 'Type': []}

# Define a regular expression pattern to match smileys
pattern = r'([\U0001F600-\U0001F64F\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF])'

# Iterate over the comments
for comment in comments:
    # Extract smileys and their types from the comment
    smileys = re.findall(pattern, comment)
    
    # Increment the count and store the smileys and their types
    for smiley in smileys:
        if smiley in smiley_data['Smiley']:
            index = smiley_data['Smiley'].index(smiley)
            smiley_data['Count'][index] += 1
        else:
            smiley_data['Smiley'].append(smiley)
            smiley_data['Count'].append(1)
            smiley_data['Type'].append(emoji.demojize(smiley))
            
# Create a DataFrame from the smiley data
smiley_df = pd.DataFrame(smiley_data)

# Sort the DataFrame by count in descending order
smiley_df = smiley_df.sort_values(by='Count', ascending=False)

# Print the smiley data
smiley_df
```

I am majorly not sure if my below code block is getting all the smileys

```
# Define a regular expression pattern to match smileys
pattern = r'([\U0001F600-\U0001F64F\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF])'
```

would like to know what can I do with this analysis. something else on top of it - some charts maybe?

I am also sharing a test dataset that will generate similar smiley counts as those available in my real data. Please note that the test dataset only has known smileys if there is something else. it won't be there like in a real dataset.

**Test Dataset**

```
import random
import pandas as pd

smileys = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

# Additional smileys to complete the required count
additional_smileys = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
                      '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
                      '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

# Combine the required smileys and additional smileys
all_smileys = smileys + additional_smileys

# Set a random seed for reproducibility
random.seed(42)

# Generate a single review
def generate_review(with_smiley=False):
    review = "This movie"
    if with_smiley:
        review += " " + random.choice(all_smileys)
    review += " is "
    review += random.choice(["amazing", "excellent", "fantastic", "brilliant", "great", "good", "okay", "average",
                             "mediocre", "disappointing", "terrible", "awful", "horrible"])
    review += random.choice(["!", "!!", "!!!", ".", "..", "..."]) + " "
    review += random.choice(["Highly recommended", "Definitely worth watching", "A must-see", "I loved it",
                             "Not worth your time", "Skip it"]) + random.choice(["!", "!!", "!!!"])
    return review

# Generate the random dataset
def generate_dataset():
    dataset = []
    review_count = 5000

    # Generate reviews with top smileys
    for smiley, count, _ in top_smileys:
        while count > 0:
            review = generate_review(with_smiley=True)
            if smiley in review:
                dataset.append(review)
                count -= 1

    # Generate reviews with additional smileys
    additional_smileys_count = len(additional_smileys)
    additional_smileys_per_review = review_count - len(dataset)
    additional_smileys_per_review = min(additional_smileys_per_review, additional_smileys_count)

    for _ in range(additional_smileys_per_review):
        review = generate_review(with_smiley=True)
        dataset.append(review)

    # Generate reviews without smileys
    while len(dataset) < review_count:
        review = generate_review()
        dataset.append(review)

    # Shuffle the dataset
    random.shuffle(dataset)
    return dataset

# List of top smileys and their counts
top_smileys = [
    ('', 331, ':thumbs_up:'),
    ('', 50, ':OK_hand:'),
    ('', 41, ':smiling_face_with_heart-eyes:'),
    ('', 38, ':light_skin_tone:'),
    ('', 35, ':smiling_face_with_smiling_eyes:'),
    ('', 14, ':slightly_smiling_face:'),
    ('', 12, ':thumbs_down:'),
    ('', 12, ':grinning_face_with_big_eyes:'),
    ('', 10, ':medium-light_skin_tone:'),
    ('', 10, ':pile_of_poo:')
]

# Generate the dataset
dataset = generate_dataset()

# Create a data frame with 'Document' column
df = pd.DataFrame({'Document': dataset})

# Display the DataFrame
df
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A big thanks to your reproducible example! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

If you prefer to use `emoji` package, you can do:

```
import emoji

text = df['Document'].str.cat(sep='\n')
out = (pd.DataFrame(emoji.emoji_list(text)).value_counts('emoji')
         .rename_axis('Smiley').rename('Count').reset_index()
         .assign(Type=lambda x: x['Smiley'].apply(emoji.demojize)))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Smiley  Count                              Type
0           331                       :thumbs_up:
1            50                         :OK_hand:
2            41                 :light_skin_tone:
3            41    :smiling_face_with_heart-eyes:
4            35  :smiling_face_with_smiling_eyes:
5            15           :slightly_smiling_face:
6            14                     :thumbs_down:
7            13     :grinning_face_with_big_eyes:
8            10          :medium-light_skin_tone:
9            10                     :pile_of_poo:
10            3        :winking_face_with_tongue:
11            3                             :owl:
12            2                           :robot:
13            2             :expressionless_face:
14            2                           :alien:
15            2                   :shushing_face:
16            2                     :crying_face:
17            2                       :zany_face:
18            2              :see-no-evil_monkey:
19            2            :speak-no-evil_monkey:
20            1          :smiling_face_with_halo:
21            1                   :face_vomiting:
22            1       :face_with_hand_over_mouth:
23            1                      :clown_face:
24            1    :smiling_face_with_open_hands:
25            1          :face_with_rolling_eyes:
26            1         :grinning_squinting_face:
27            1                            :frog:
28            1            :face_with_open_mouth:
29            1                           :panda:
30            1   :kissing_face_with_closed_eyes:
31            1    :smiling_face_with_sunglasses:
32            1             :face_blowing_a_kiss:
```

---

You can use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to avoid a loop then use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to count the number of occurences. Finally, *"demojize"* each smiley (the slowest part):

```
out = (df['Document'].str.extractall(pattern).value_counts()
                     .rename_axis('Smiley').rename('Count').reset_index()
                     .assign(Type=lambda x: x['Smiley'].apply(emoji.demojize)))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Smiley  Count                              Type
0           331                       :thumbs_up:
1            50                         :OK_hand:
2            41                 :light_skin_tone:
3            41    :smiling_face_with_heart-eyes:
4            35  :smiling_face_with_smiling_eyes:
5            15           :slightly_smiling_face:
6            14                     :thumbs_down:
7            13     :grinning_face_with_big_eyes:
8            10                     :pile_of_poo:
9            10          :medium-light_skin_tone:
10            3        :winking_face_with_tongue:
11            2             :expressionless_face:
12            2              :see-no-evil_monkey:
13            2                     :crying_face:
14            2            :speak-no-evil_monkey:
15            2                           :alien:
16            1    :smiling_face_with_sunglasses:
17            1             :face_blowing_a_kiss:
18            1   :kissing_face_with_closed_eyes:
19            1                            :frog:
20            1          :smiling_face_with_halo:
21            1            :face_with_open_mouth:
22            1         :grinning_squinting_face:
23            1          :face_with_rolling_eyes:
24            1                           :panda:
```

> The pattern part is correct? I am not missing out on any emoticons?

Your pattern is not right. I don't know the full list you want to extract but below you have a code to debug it:

```
#     add latin1 codes --v
pattern2 = '([\\U00000000-\\U000000FF\\U0001F600-\\U0001F64F\\U0001F300-\\U0001F5FF\\U0001F680-\\U0001F6FF\\U0001F1E0-\\U0001F1FF])'

other = df['Document'].str.replace(pattern2, '', regex=True)
print(other[other != ''])

# Output / Missed emojis
1149    
1238    
1305    
1424    
1978    
2611    
2623    
2959    
3717    
4045    
4067    
4699    
4975    
Name: Document, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, but the pattern part is correct? I am not missing out on any emoticons?

Comment: The pattern doesn't find all emoji.  And it splits some emoji apart into multiple emoji (emoji can consist of multiple characters). The emoji package has a several functions to find/count emoji in a string instead of using a regular expression pattern. See https://carpedm20.github.io/emoji/docs/#extracting-emoji

Comment: I updated my answer according your comment. If you missed some emojis the code above will should be find them.

Comment: @Corralien Yes, there are a lot of emoticons that I have missed. how to include everything that is not text but symbol or emoji.

Comment: @cuzi thanks for sharing the link. I will go through it to see the options

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @corralien and @cuzi, I was able to get my final result using the below code. It doesn't use patterns but uses  `emoji.analyze(text, join_emoji=True)` function: -

```
import emoji

out = (df['Document'].apply(lambda text: [token.chars for token in emoji.analyze(text, join_emoji=True) 
                       if isinstance(token.value, emoji.EmojiMatch)]).explode().value_counts()
                      .rename_axis('Smiley').rename('Count').reset_index())

out
```

> Output

```
index   Smiley  Count
0     331
1     50
2     41
3     41
4     35
5     15
6     14
7     13
8     10
9     10
10    3
11    3
12    2
13    2
14    2
15    2
16    2
17    2
18    2
19    2
20    1
21    1
22    1
23    1
24    1
25    1
26    1
27    1
28    1
29    1
30    1
31    1
32    1
```